# URLencode dates inside of a javascript function

Tags: urlencode

i need to URLEncode a date value that is taken from a datepicker control on my page. Currently I am trying to use the escape function to do this, but it is not working.

example: escape(datevalue);

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, using EncodeURIComponent.